# parse String and put it into tab title

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, android-viewpager

i want to parse my xml and display the strings they i have parse on my pagetitles.But i get a nullponiterexception.

here is my splashactivity:

```
package de.heron.xmlpullparser;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import de.heron.R;
import de.heron.SettingsActivity;
import de.heron.model.RoomReader;
import de.heron.parser.RoomParser;

public class SplashActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private RoomParser mNewsFeeder;
    private List<RoomReader> mRssFeedList;
    private static final String TOPSTORIES =
            "URL";
    public static String[] TabTitles = {RoomReader.getName()};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_striptabs);
        mRssFeedList = new ArrayList<RoomReader>();
        new DoRssFeedTask().execute(TOPSTORIES);    
    }

    static class RssHolder {
        //textview textview1; usw...

    }

    public class DoRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RoomReader>> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String jsonStr = null;
        Handler innerHandler;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Context context = getContext();
            prog = new ProgressDialog(SplashActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<RoomReader> doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (String urlVal : params) {
                mNewsFeeder = new RoomParser(urlVal);
            }
            mRssFeedList = mNewsFeeder.parse();
            return mRssFeedList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RoomReader> result) {
            prog.dismiss();
            String key = "key";
             Bundle b=new Bundle();
             b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{RoomReader.getName()});
             Intent i=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
             i.putExtras(b);
             SplashActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }  
  }
```

here is my fragment adapter:

```
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
String key = "key";
        Bundle b = MainActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
    //public final String[] TITLES =  b.getStringArray(key);
        public final String[] TITLES = SplashActivity.TabTitles;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return SplashActivity.TabTitles[position];//TITLES[position];

             }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(Fragment1.position, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        /*@Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  
            switch (position) {  
            case 0:  
                return fragment = new Fragment1();  
            case 1:  
                return fragment = new Fragment2();
            default:  
                break;  
            }  
            return fragment;  
    }*/

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }
    }
```

and here is my asyntask in my mainactivty :

```
 private class RssAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomReader> {
        public RssAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RoomReader> rssFeedLst) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, rssFeedLst);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            RssHolder rssHolder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                //textview id setzten usw..
                view.setTag(rssHolder);
            } else {
                rssHolder = (RssHolder) view.getTag();
                //textview set text RoomReader.getName() usw...
            }

            return view;
        }
    }

    static class RssHolder {
        //textview textview1; usw...

    }

    public class DoRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RoomReader>> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String jsonStr = null;
        Handler innerHandler;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Context context = getContext();
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<RoomReader> doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (String urlVal : params) {
                mNewsFeeder = new RoomParser(urlVal);
            }
            mRssFeedList = mNewsFeeder.parse();
            return mRssFeedList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RoomReader> result) {
            prog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
}
```

the oncreate from my mainactivity:

```
 private ListView mRssListView;
    private RoomParser mNewsFeeder;
    private List<RoomReader> mRssFeedList;
    private RssAdapter mRssAdap;
    private static final String TOPSTORIES =
            "the url";
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
     private static TextToSpeech tts;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_striptabs);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mRssFeedList = new ArrayList<RoomReader>();
        new DoRssFeedTask().execute(TOPSTORIES);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }
```

Log:

```
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.heron/de.heron.xmlpullparser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:200)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:182)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at de.heron.xmlpullparser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-12 18:06:00.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21128):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What line is your NPE detected on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest parsing the URL before opening the MainActivity. e.g you could create a Splashscreen activity and write your asyncTask there to parse the URL and then on the onPostExecute() method of the asyncTask in your splashScreen activity you could create an intent to the MainActivity. You could pass the parsed strings to the MainActivity using the intent methods( intent.putExtra() ) or simply setting some static variables.

```
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);


            new DataFromServer().execute();

        }

        private class DataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPreExecute();



            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreen.this,
                "Loading...",
                "Please wait while Ads are being loaded", true,
                false);

           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /* fetch the data from server here and set the titles variables of the
                           MainActivity */
            // e.g 
            MainActivity.tab1_title = some_data_from_server;
            MainActivity.tab2_title = some_data_from_server;
            MainActivity.tab3_title = some_data_from_server;

        return null;
          }


         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("tab1: ",MainActivity.tab1_title);
                        Log.e("tab2: ",MainActivity.tab2_title);
                        Log.e("tab3: ",MainActivity.tab3_title);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.Class);
            StartActivity(intent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();

            if (progressDialog != null) { 
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String tab1_title;
public static String tab2_title;
public static String tab3_title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Now you can use the tab1_title, tab2_title and tab3_title here
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your fast answer i try it out and say it you when it work.

Comment: i want now to do what Sayed Jalil Hassan say, but i have another question,

why can i parse a Array between Activitys.

Comment: ok your solution dosn´t work i get a nullpointer exception too.When i use hard coded strings in TITLES string i doesn´t get a error.

Comment: See my edited answer and log the title variables in the asynctask to make sure the data from server is not null. bw you can also fill a static array in the same manner.